# Java method call listener

Tags: java, observable, listener

I have a class `Person` and I'd like to be aware of every call to getFirstName() method:

```
public class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public Person() {...}

   public String getFirstName() {
      return this.firstName
   }

   //... Rest of getters and setters
}
```

So when somebody does this, I'd like to print out "Hello world" for example (actual use would be more complicated):

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Person person = new Person("John", "Doe");
      person.getFirstName();
   }
```

However I want to do this without modifying `Person` class (at least NOT before compilation). I read sth about Observable pattern and Property Change Listeners, but they don't seem to be doing what I'd want. Is such thing even possible in java ?

Comment: You're trying to make a class behave as if it were observable, but without giving it the wiring to allow this to be so (your "Person cannot be modified" requirement). As I see it you have two options: 1) Change your requirements so that Person is in fact wired to be observed, or 2) Give up on this

Comment: Edit: I was wrong, as there is a way using an aspect-oriented library or approach. [Other similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+listen+to+method+call+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27233494/4107107), but what if i want to listen to more than just one method or even more than one class.