# Spring + Kotlin - Is it possible to detect certain functions calls?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I've just started using Spring and Kotlin and wanted to ask is it possible for my app to detect certain function calls?

For example, say I have:

```
fun getSuccessMessage() : String {
        return "great"
}
```

Then in my app runner I call that:

```
@Component
class AppRunner: CommandLineRunner {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        getSuccessMessage()
    }
}
```

Can I have another function thats listening and acts whenever its called:

```
fun doSomethingWhenSuccessCalled() {
   // I'm imaging some magic Spring annotation where I can say 
   //something like @ListeningTo("getSuccessMessage")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. 
To read more about listener of method invoke look at:
[Listener on Method.invoke java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233276/listener-on-method-invoke-java)